# Replace outliers in Pandas dataframe by NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, nan, outliers

I'd like to replace outliers by np.nan. I have a dataframe containing floats, int and NaNs such as:

```
df_ex = pd.DataFrame({
'a': [np.nan,np.nan,2.0,-0.5,6,120], 
'b': [1, 3, 4, 2,40,11], 
'c': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4,2,2], 
'd': [6, 2.2, np.nan, 0,3,3],
'e': [12, 4, np.nan, -5,5,5],
'f': [2, 3, 8, 2,12,8],
'g': [3, 3, 9.0, 11, np.nan,2]})
```

[image: generated dataframe]

with this function:

```
def outliers(s, replace=np.nan):
Q1, Q3 = np.percentile(s, [25 ,75])
IQR = Q3-Q1
return s.where((s >= (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) & (s <= (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)), replace)

df_ex_o = df_ex.apply(outliers, axis=1)
```

but I get:

[image: resulting dataframe]

Any idea on what's going on? I'd like the outliers to be calculated column wise.

Thanks as always for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `apply` here is the annotated code for the optimized version:

```
def mask_outliers(df, replace):
    # Calculate Q1 and Q2 quantile
    q = df.agg('quantile', q=[.25, .75])

    # Calculate IQR = Q2 - Q1
    iqr = q.loc[.75] - q.loc[.25]

    # Calculate lower and upper limits to decide outliers
    lower = q.loc[.25] - 1.5 * iqr
    upper = q.loc[.75] + 1.5 * iqr

    # Replace the values that does not lies between [lower, upper]
    return df.where(df.ge(lower) & df.le(upper), replace)
```

##### Result

```
mask_outliers(df_ex, np.nan)

     a     b    c    d    e   f     g
0  NaN   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   2   3.0
1  NaN   3.0  2.0  2.2  4.0   3   3.0
2  2.0   4.0  3.0  NaN  NaN   8   9.0
3 -0.5   2.0  4.0  NaN  NaN   2  11.0
4  6.0   NaN  2.0  3.0  5.0  12   NaN
5  NaN  11.0  2.0  3.0  5.0   8   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides an answer to the question:

*Any idea on what's going on? I'd like the outliers to be calculated column wise.*

where the another (accepted) answer provides only a better solution to what you want to achieve.

---

The are two issues to fix in order to make your code doing what it should:

- the `NaN` values have to be removed from the column before calculating `np.percentile()` to avoid getting for both Q1 and Q3 the value of NaN.

This is one of the reasons for so many NaN values you see in the result of applying your code to the DataFrame. `np.percentile()` behaves here another way as Pandas `.agg('quantile',...)` which calculates the Q1 and Q3 thresholds skipping implicit the NaN values from consideration.

- the value for the axis has to be changed from `1` to `0` (i.e. to  `.apply(outliers, axis=0)`) in order to apply outliers column wise.

This is another reason for so many NaN values you see in the result you got. The only row without all values set to `NaN` is these one which does not have a `NaN` value in itself, else also in these row all the values would be set to `NaN` for the reason explained above.

Following changes to your code:

```
    colmn_noNaN = colmn.dropna()
    Q1, Q3 = np.percentile(colmn_noNaN, [25 ,75])
```

and

```
df_ex_o = df_ex.apply(outliers, axis=0)
```

will solve the issues. Below the entire code and its output:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
df_ex = pd.DataFrame({
'a': [np.nan,np.nan,2.0,-0.5,6,120], 
'b': [1, 3, 4, 2,40,11], 
'c': [np.nan, 2, 3, 4,2,2], 
'd': [6, 2.2, np.nan, 0,3,3],
'e': [12, 4, np.nan, -5,5,5],
'f': [2, 3, 8, 2,12,8],
'g': [3, 3, 9.0, 11, np.nan,2]})
# print(df_ex)
def outliers(colmn, replace=np.nan):
    colmn_noNaN = colmn.dropna()
    Q1, Q3 = np.percentile(colmn_noNaN, [25 ,75])
    IQR = Q3-Q1
    return colmn.where((colmn >= (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) & (colmn <= (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR)), replace)

df_ex_o = df_ex.apply(outliers, axis = 0)
print(df_ex_o)
```

gives:

```
     a     b    c    d    e   f     g
0  NaN   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   2   3.0
1  NaN   3.0  2.0  2.2  4.0   3   3.0
2  2.0   4.0  3.0  NaN  NaN   8   9.0
3 -0.5   2.0  4.0  NaN  NaN   2  11.0
4  6.0   NaN  2.0  3.0  5.0  12   NaN
5  NaN  11.0  2.0  3.0  5.0   8   2.0
```

Comment: thanks @Claudio for an alternative, there are so many different angles to tackle the same problem in Python and Pandas.

Comment: See my updated answer for explanations on *Any idea on what's going on?* and improved code providing the same result as the Pandas code does.